# Doing mutual exclusive checkbox of two buttons with siblings()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get two buttons groups with checkboxes mutually exclusive.

Here's my current result on this [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ysis81/2z19gw3b/1/)

As you can see, there are four divs (with `id="UserVsComputer"`, `id="User1VsUser2"`, `id="PlayableHits"` and `id="button-new-game"`).

I want the two first `<div>` ( `UserVsComputer` and `User1VsUser2` )  to be mutually exclusive when we click on the checkbox of concerning `<input>` (i.e corresponding to the right `<div>`).

In JavaScript part, I did:

```
// Select the clicked checkbox for game type                                          
   $('input.game').on('click',function(){                                                
     setGameType();
   }); 
       
   function setGameType() {
   // Get state of the first clicked element 
   var element = $('#UserVsComputer input.game');
   var checkBoxState = element.prop('checked');
   // Set !checkBoxState for the sibling checkbox, i.e the other
   element.siblings().find('input.game').prop('checked',!checkBoxState);
   updateGameType();
   }
  
   function updateGameType() {
   // Set type of game
   if ($('#UserVsComputer input').prop('checked'))
     gameType = 'UserVsComputer';
   else
     gameType = 'User1VsUser2';
   }
```

I don't want the `<div id="PlayableHits" class="checkbox">` to be concerned by this mutual exclusion on two first checkboxes.

For example, below a capture showing that I can set the two first checkbox to true without making them exclusive:

[image: Example of not working exclusive checkboxes]

What might be wrong here?

Comment: Check your `element` - it is the checkbox so you are looking for siblings of it, not the containing `DIV`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following - it uses the target of the click event to ascertain which checkbox was checked:

```
// Select the clicked checkbox for game type
$('input.game').on('click',function(e){
  setGameType(e.target);
});

function setGameType(cb) {
  var container = $(cb).parent().parent();
  var checkBox = $(cb);
  var checkBoxState = checkBox.prop('checked');

  // Set !checkBoxState for the sibling checkbox, i.e the other
  container.siblings().find('input.game').prop('checked', !checkBoxState);
  updateGameType();
}

function updateGameType() {
  // Set type of game
  if ($('#UserVsComputer input').prop('checked')) {
    gameType = 'UserVsComputer';
  } else {
    gameType = 'User1VsUser2';
  }
}
```

There are other bits which could use some attention (the hardcoded `.parent().parent()` isn't pretty but works in this case..

Comment: -@Forty3 Thanks for your answer. Just a last question, what's the difference between `cb` and `$(cb)` : I realize that I can't access to checkbox state with cb.prop('checked') but I can with $(cb).prop('checked'), why ? regards

Comment: `cb` gets the value of `e.target` which is a simple DOM element and not a jQuery object. Wrapping it in `$()` converts it to a jQuery object giving it `.prop()` availability.